# Functions containing a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my assignment: 
Write a function named count_letters that takes as a parameter a string and returns a dictionary that tabulates how many of each letter is in that string. The string can contain characters other than letters, but only the letters should be counted. The string could even be the empty string. Lower-case and upper-case versions of a letter should be part of the same count. The keys of the dictionary should be the upper-case letters. If a letter does not appear in the string, then it would not get added to the dictionary. For example, if the string is

"AaBb"
then the dictionary that is returned should contain these key-value pairs:

{'A': 2, 'B': 2}

This is my code:

```
def count_letters(string):
    d = dict()
    for x in string:
        if x not in d:
            d[x]= 0
        else:
            d[x] += 1
    return d
```

It is not returning the correct numbers in the string. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You did not address the requirement *Lower-case and upper-case versions of a letter should be part of the same count.* in your code.

Comment: And also not the requirement *The string can contain characters other than letters, but only the letters should be counted.*.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment says that only letters should be counted, but you're counting everything.

The assignment says that upper- and lower-case versions of a letter should be counted together, but you're not mapping case.

When you create a new dictionary entry, it should start as `1` to count the current element, not `0`.

```
import char

def count_letters(string):
    d = dict()
    for x in string:
        if char.isalpha(x): # only count letters
            x = x.upper() # Convert lowercase to uppercase equivalent
            if x not in d:
                d[x]= 1
            else:
                d[x] += 1
    return d
```

Comment: d[x] = 0 should probably be d[x] = 1 otherwise the count will be off by one

Comment: Good catch, added that to the answer.